# Search using dropdown options with additional filtering - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add the option when 'recommendation' or 'source' is selected from dropdown, to get all Candidates which have in one of those two columns something other than null or '0', and sort them using 'created_at', from-to date.

This is my view:

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <form class="search-form search-form-basic" action="/candidates/index" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-row">              
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                <label for="search_email">First name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="search_first_name" id="search_first_name" class="form-control" @if(isset(Session::get('inputs')['search_first_name'])) value="{{ Session::get('inputs')['search_first_name'] }}" @endif>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                <label for="search_last_name">Last name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="search_last_name" id="search_last_name" class="form-control" @if(isset(Session::get('inputs')['search_last_name'])) value="{{ Session::get('inputs')['search_last_name'] }}" @endif>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                <label for="search_round_number">Round Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="search_round_number" id="search_round_number" class="form-control" placeholder="" @if(isset(Session::get('inputs')['search_round_number'])) value="{{ Session::get('inputs')['search_round_number'] }}" @endif>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                <label for="search_location">location:</label>
                <input type="text" name="search_location" id="search_location" class="form-control" 
                 @if(isset(Session::get('inputs')['search_location'])) value="{{ Session::get('inputs')['search_location'] }}" @endif>
            </div> 
            <select name="options" class="col-md-4 form-group">
             <option value="">--- Select From ---</option>
              <option  value="birth_date">Birth Date</option>
              <option  value="CV_grade_date">CV Grade Date</option>
              <option  value="source">Source</option>
              <option  value="recommendation">Recommended</option>                
              <option  value="created_at">Applied</option>
            </select>
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                <label for="search_from_date">From:</label>
                <input type="date" name="search_from_date" id="search_from_date" class="form-control" 
                 @if(isset(Session::get('inputs')['search_from_date'])) value="{{ Session::get('inputs')['search_from_date'] }}" @endif>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                <label for="search_to_date">To:</label>
                <input type="date" name="search_to_date" id="search_to_date" class="form-control" 
                 @if(isset(Session::get('inputs')['search_to_date'])) value="{{ Session::get('inputs')['search_to_date'] }}" @endif>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Search</button>
                <a href="/users" class="btn btn-custom"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Clear</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my Controller, where i tried to implement adding a new variable with value of either 'recommendation' or 'source', assign that value to a new variable, and then drop the $options variable, so I skip

```
        ->when($options, function ($query) use ($options,$search_from_date,$search_to_date  ) {
           return $query->whereBetween($options, array($search_from_date, $search_to_date));
```

Here is my code:

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    if($request->isMethod('post')){
    $search_first_name =    $request->search_first_name;
    $search_last_name =     $request->search_last_name;
    $search_email =         $request->search_email;
    $search_round_number =  $request->search_round_number;
    $search_location =      $request->search_location;

    $options = Input::get('dropdown');

    if($options == 'recommendation' || 'source')   {
            $recOrSource = Input::get('options');
            unset($options);  
    }

    $search_from_date =      $request->search_from_date;
    $search_to_date =      $request->search_to_date;

    $candidate = DB::table('candidates')
                ->when($search_first_name, function ($query) use ($search_first_name) {
                    return $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search_first_name . '%');
                })
                ->when($search_last_name, function ($query) use ($search_last_name) {
                    return $query->where('last_name', 'like', '%' . $search_last_name . '%');
                })
                ->when($search_email, function ($query) use ($search_email) {
                    return $query->where('email', $search_email);
                })
                ->when($search_round_number, function ($query) use ($search_round_number) {
                    return $query->where('round_number', $search_round_number);
                })
                ->when($search_location, function ($query) use ($search_location) {
                   return $query->where('location', $search_location);
                })                       
                ->when($options, function ($query) use ($options,$search_from_date,$search_to_date  ) {
                   return $query->whereBetween($options, array($search_from_date, $search_to_date));
                })    
                ->when($recOrSource, function ($query) use ($recOrSource,$search_from_date,$search_to_date  ) {
                   return $query->where(!empty($recOrSource))->whereBetween('created_at', array($search_from_date, $search_to_date));
                })                                                                                     
                ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
                ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
                ->get();                     

                Session::flash('inputs', [
                    'search_first_name' => $search_first_name,
                    'search_last_name' => $search_last_name,
                    'search_email' => $search_email,
                    'search_round_number' => $search_round_number,
                    'search_from_date' => $search_from_date,
                    'search_to_date' => $search_to_date,
                    'search_location' => $search_location

                    ]);
            }else{
                 Session::forget('inputs');


    $candidate = Candidate::orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
                    ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
                    ->get();
                }

    return view('/candidates/index', [
        'candidate' => $candidate
    ]);
```

}

The error I get is "Undefined variable: options", However I didn't find a way to resolve this.
And I did see similar questions but nothing was working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In your *view* the `<select>` name attribute is **options**, but in your *controller* you are retrieving the value of **dropdown** `$options = Input::get('dropdown');`. It should be:

> $options = Input::get('options');

2) If you want check if the selected option is `recommendation` or `source`, your if statement should be:

> if ($options == 'recommendation' || $options == 'source')

3) Inside your *if statement* you are unsetting $options variable, but lines below you have `when($option,..`, then you should change `unset($options);` to:

> $options = null;

otherwise it will throw "Undefined variable: options" again.

4) Also, in your controller you using `->when($recOrSource,..`, but the variable `$recOrSource` is declared inside your `if statement`, so If you don't select "recommended" or "source", you will get "Undefined variable: recOrSource". To fix that you should declare `$recOrSource` i.e. outside your *if statement*.

```
$recOrSource = null;

if ($options == 'recommendation' || $options == 'source') {
```

---

Wrapping up, the changes you should do in your *controller*:

```
...
$options = Input::get('options');
$recOrSource = null;

if($options == 'recommendation' || $options == 'source')   {
    $recOrSource = Input::get('options');
    $options = null;
}
...
```